# How to add Text to end of each image name when scraping with Python

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am downloading four images from a website.  I want each image to be named the SKU and then (1), (2) etc.

I have managed to write the code to download each file however it is currently overwriting each one as they are all named the same.

What do I need to do in my code to make each one have the number at the end?

```
for image in images:
    if(image.get('src').startswith('https://imageapi.partsdb.com.au/api/Image')):
        link = (image.get('src'))
        name = soup.find("div",{"class":"head2BR"}).text
        with open(name + '.jpg','wb') as f:
            im = requests.get(link) 
            f.write(im.content)
            print('Writing:', name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function - which will yield the item along with its index.

```
for index, image in enumerate(images, start=1):
    if(image.get('src').startswith('https://imageapi.partsdb.com.au/api/Image')):
        link = (image.get('src'))
        name = f'{soup.find("div", {"class": "head2BR"}).text} ({index})'

        with open(name + '.jpg','wb') as f:
            im = requests.get(link) 
            f.write(im.content)
            print('Writing:', name)
```

Comment: This does change the name and outputs all images but not quite what I need. It has changed the Zero on the end of the sku (in this case KBR1510) to a different number rather than adding something on the end.  I need the SKU to remain the same - with a -1, -2 or (1), (2) at the end.  I am still learning and wanted to loop around multiple pages to scrape product images so the file needs to still have the full SKU as part of the name.

Comment: @LyndaHarmer Does changing `name` to  `name = f'{soup.find("div", {"class": "head2BR"}).text ({index})}'` work?

Comment: No it doesn't sorry :(  I get the following error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @LyndaHarmer I think that was my problem. I edited the answer. Does it work?

Comment: Yes thank you!!!! It works.  Now to just figure out how to loop around each page on the site to grab images for each product - wish me luck!!  Thanks so much for your help :)